# Logarithm of a complex function on a non-simply connected space

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, connectedness

It can be proven that on a simply connected set $U$ in $\mathbb{C}$ where a function $f$ has no zeroes there is a function $g$ such that $e^g = f$ on $U$. This is done by observing that $\frac{f'}{f}$ is holomorphic and therefore has a "primitive".

I suspect that the requirement that $U$ be simply connected is sufficient, but not required. This comes from an exercise I've been trying to solve:

> Consider $U=\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ -1,1 \}$. This set is obviously not
>   simply connected, and the function $f(z) = z^2 -1$ has no zeroes on
>   it. Does there exist an holomorphic function $h$ on $U$ such that $e^{h(z)}=f(z)$ on $U$?

Is there really such a function or is simple-connectedness necessary?

Comment: if $f$ is never zero in a domain, one can always get a *local* logarithm as one can fix a branch on a small disc around any point but as noted in the answer by @Robert, the problem comes from trying to match the values when you go on a closed curve encircling points (not in the domain) where $f$ is zero; sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't when the domain is not simply connected - one example when it works (so there is $\log f$ on $U$) is for $U=\mathbb C -[-1,1], f(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ as opposed to same domain but $f_1(z)=1-z^2$ when it doesn't work and there is no $\log f_1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f = e^h$ on $U$, $$\oint_C \dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)} \; dz = \oint_C h'(z) \; dz = 0$$
for any closed contour $C$ in $U$.  But (using the residue theorem) if $f$ has zeros
inside $C$ (even if they are not in $U$), that integral will not be $0$.